# Error when removing button programmatically with custom template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom template to my button that is as follow:

```
<!--Button Template-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="buttonBorderOuter"
                        BorderBrush="#DBDBDB"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="#00ECECEC"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Margin="1">
                    <Border x:Name="buttonBorderInner">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <!--<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" />-->
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                    <Border.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="#FFECECEC"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="#00ECECEC"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Border.Triggers>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="#ECECEC"
                                TargetName="buttonBorderOuter" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="#FDFDFD"
                                TargetName="buttonBorderInner" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                Value="1"
                                TargetName="buttonBorderInner" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius"
                                Value="4"
                                TargetName="buttonBorderInner" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The button is working fine in almost any case. I can hover it and see the animations and I can click it and see the animations. The only thing that throws an error is when I click the button and remove it from the view.

I'm writing an WPF application (as you maybe could tell from the XAML in above code) That has the following 'Command':

```
public ICommand AddEquipmentFilterToList
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    Equipment equipment = SegmentRequirementEquipment[SelectedEquipmentFilterIndex];

                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Content = equipment.ID;
                    button.Padding = new Thickness(2.5);
                    button.Click += (o, i) =>
                        {
                            EquipmentFilters.Remove(button);
                        };
                    EquipmentFilters.Add(button);
                });
        }
    }
```

Here I add a button to an 'ObservableCollection' that is linked to this control in the view:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EquipmentFilters}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

As you can see in my C# code, when I click on the button it should be removed from the list and therefore from the view. When I do this (clicking the button) I get the following error:

> 'Background' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'

I assume it is because the 'MouseLeave' event triggers but can't find a 'Button' to change its background.

Is there a way to fix this error or is my custom template poorly designed? This is the first time I try to edit my visual presentation and would love to learn how to do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a decent way (in code) but it should work.

Start the animation in code, not triggers; so you have a chance to check if the button has been removed, in which case, do not start the animation.

```
button.MouseEnter += (s, e) => { /*begin Storyboard*/};
button.MouseLeave += (s, e) => 
    {
        if (EquipmentFilters.Contains(button))
        {
            //begin storyboard
        }                           
    };
button.Click += (o, i) =>
    {
        EquipmentFilters.Remove(button);
    };
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this solely in XAML?